# Are the relativistic masses conserved in nuclear fission?

Tags: special-relativity, nuclear-physics, mass, conservation-laws

If A $\rightarrow$ B+C+ΔE, then

$M_{B}+M_{C}< M_{A}$ So, whether the masses involved were the relativistic or the rest, they aren't conserved. So, why would anyone say the rest masses, not the relativistic masses, are the ones that transform into energy, how to determine which is which?

Comment: [Relativistic mass is a deprecated concept](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/133376/)

Comment: This is an _epic_ example of why teaching & learning "arbitrary mass" is a poor idea.

Comment: Do any fission products travel at relativistic speeds ?? Certainly you want the neutrons to be travelling slowly to maximise the chance of being captured by another nucleus and sustaining the chain reaction.

Comment: Just imagine they would for the sake of the argument.